# android backspace issue in activity group

Tags: android, activitygroup, backspace

My app uses ActivityGroup to build. There are four sub-activities in the ActivityGroup. No matter it is in which sub-activity, when input keyboard backspace, the sub-activity will always be changed to the first sub-activity that it is the first sub-activity when the app is run.

I cannot filter the backspace because there is an editview in one of sub-activity. And should allow user to input backspace.
My android SDK is 4.4 and the target is Google APIs - API level 18.

Anyone has encountered this issue and know why?

Comment: Are you sure about input keyboard backspace?

Comment: "My app uses ActivityGroup to build" -- `ActivityGroup` has been deprecated for **nearly four years**. Please use modern programming practices, such as fragments.

Comment: I'm sure. I run the app in emulator. And use PC keyboard to input. When input the backspace of PC keyboard. The issue happens.